# Different response from GeoServer for WMS and vector tile data in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles, mapbox-vector-tile

I have made a GeoServer basemap in WMS, and now I want to create a similar vectortile service -  using GeoServer 2.20.0 and the vector-tiles plugin.

Problem is that I get different outputs from GeoServer for a WMS and a vector-tile for the same layer in OpenLayers.

Here is an example that produces the problem:

```
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import 'ol-layerswitcher/dist/ol-layerswitcher.css';
import ImageWMS from 'ol/source/ImageWMS';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import MousePosition from 'ol/control/MousePosition';
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT';
import VectorTileLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorTile';
import VectorTileSource from 'ol/source/VectorTile';
import TileGrid from 'ol/tilegrid/TileGrid';
import LayerGroup from 'ol/layer/Group';
import {createStringXY} from 'ol/coordinate';
import {ScaleLine, defaults as defaultControls} from 'ol/control';
import {Image as ImageLayer, Tile as TileLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj';
import LayerSwitcher from 'ol-layerswitcher';
import { BaseLayerOptions, GroupLayerOptions } from 'ol-layerswitcher';

const forest = new ImageLayer({
  //extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
  visible: true,
  source: new ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'subset_skov'},
    ratio: 1,
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  }),
});

const vectorForest = new VectorTileLayer({ 
  visible: true,
  source: new VectorTileSource({
    format: new MVT(),
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    tilePixelRatio: 0, // oversampling when > 1
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/subset_skov@EPSG3857@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf',

  }),
});

const skovGroup = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'Forest',
  layers: [forest]
});

const VectorTileGroup = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'Vector tiles',
  layers: [vectorForest]
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  controls: defaultControls().extend([]),
  layers: [skovGroup,VectorTileGroup],
  
  view: new View({
    center: [1200000, 7550000],
    zoom: 8,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  }),
});

const layerSwitcher = new LayerSwitcher({
  reverse: true,
  groupSelectStyle: 'children'
});
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

In this, I use the layer 'subset_skov' which is a layer group, with three different representations of forest sizes at different zoom levels (think of it as the pregenerelize plugin functionality) - the closer you zoom in, the more forests you get.

Here is the problem - this is what I get in Openlayers :

[image: WMS and vector tile responses]

The blue outlined polygons is the vector-tile, and the green raster is the WMS on the same data.

I run GeoServer with developer logging - it thinks that everything is ok for both products.

---

Can anybody explain this behavio? Is it down to MVT formats in OL (v1/v2), is it the GeoServer vector-tile plugin or something I have been missing in OL?

Comment: looks like you have over generalised

Comment: This is server side problem of vector tile generation, not client side of displaying them with OpenLayers.

Comment: @IanTurton - For the WMS the generalization is perfect and looks good. The vectortiles is over generalized, and i am thinking it might be the vector tile plugin doing it - as TomazicM suggests...